# Tokenfield does not work with bootstrap “has-error” class

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im having trouble with tokenfield and bootstraps "has-error" class. If an input has "has-error" class without tokenfield then a red border is niceley displayed around it. When i add the tokenfield then it is not. What can i do so that "has-error" will display a red border around input tag with tokenfield?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o1167a3t/2/

code:

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
    <input id="x" class="form-control" type="text" />
</div>
// include next line to see that red border dissapears
//new Tokenfield({el: document.querySelector('#x')});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's rule selector for the red border is: `.has-error .form-control`. Tokenfield overwrites the elements inside `.has-error` and `.form-control` is lost.

You can adapt to this, by duplicating the original Bootstrap CSS rule to a new CSS file, `<style>`, etc. , but taking into account the new classes and structure:

```css
.has-error .tokenfield {
    border-color: #a94442;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/9o5q2rxu/